# 'android' and 'emulator' commands not found

Tags: android-emulator, command-line

I have installed **android-sdk-linux** on my ubuntu 12.04 netbook and I see that the commands *android* (which opens the AVD Manager) and *emulator* (to which on appending the name of a specific AVD, the AVD boots) are not found! It suggested *qemulator* But that turned out to have nothing to do with the android-sdk-linux.

I do know how to boot it via **eclipse**, where you open the AVD list and then select an AVD and click Start and then Launch.

But I don't want to go through these many stages. Instead I would like Launch it using a single command line viz. the *emulator* command, which I found on the website developer.android.com. I followed installation instructions. Yet I didn't get success.

UPDATE: As our friend suggested, I updated the $PATH variable and had partial success. However there is still an error and I have to get that rectified. Here is what panned out.

```
aneesh@nb-14:~$ export PATH=$PATH:android-sdk-linux/tools
aneesh@nb-14:~$ emulator @Andreud
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
```

Comment: Have you setup your `$PATH` variable correspondingly (to include the Android Emulator's directories which hold those executables)?

Comment: Thanks very much! I updated the $PATH variable and updated the question also.

Comment: Superb! But placing the answer inside the question is suboptimal :) Would you like to convert it into an answer (you can answer your own question, and are even encouraged to do so) -- or do you prefer me doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error stating that the AVD's config is missing a Kernel file is because when I checked the AVD Manager, the concerned AVD had a red cross-mark against it! Once I repaired this AVD I found that the error was eliminated!

Answer (score 0):

Need to add emulator -"$ANDROID_INSTALLATION/Android/Sdk/emulator" to your $PATH variable.
after adding the path variable you will need to restart the terminal session.
and / or you can permanently add the path variable by editing the bashrc/profile file depending your distribution.